# Erlang - open a file like double clicking on it

Tags: file, erlang, png

Is there a way in erlang to open file in the same way it will open when I double click it?
Open using the application associated with the type of the file.

Specific I need to open png file.

Thanks!

Comment: for Linux there is stuff like https://linux.die.net/man/1/xdg-open , in Windows you can run start.exe, what OS are you interested in?

Comment: I'm using linux (ubuntu if it's important). Can I use this linux.die.net/man/1/xdg-open in erlang code?

Comment: `xdg-open` an OS command (should come with your desktop) that you can run using `os.cmd` in erlang

Comment: Great, it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
os:cmd("xdg-open my-image.png").
```